# Canvas Layers (Z Index)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I understand that Canvas is as ink dries and each item that is draw is on top.

I'm having a little problem, I have a list of sources of background images

```
                var sources = {
                  bg: 'images/room-1/bg.png',
                  rightWall: 'images/room-1/wall-right.png',
                  leftWall: 'images/room-1/wall-left.png',
                  beam: 'images/room-1/beam-left.png',
                  sofa: 'images/room-1/sofa.png'
                };

                loadImages(sources, function(images) {
                  context.drawImage(images.bg, 0, 0, 760, 500);
                  context.drawImage(images.rightWall, 714, 0, 46, 392);
                  context.drawImage(images.leftWall, 0, 160, 194,322);
                  context.drawImage(images.beam, 0, 45, 143,110);
                  context.drawImage(images.sofa, 194, 280, 436,140);
                });
```

This is fine and they order how I like.

My issue is I have an image upload for a user to upload their image into the Canvas.

I am just using an upload box to test the theory, but the idea is the user will upload their image, crop, scale it, using JQuery / PHP and this saves the image. I will then grab this manipulated URL and pull this in, however the problem is that the Canvas is loaded so when i upload an image, it goes on top off the sources image.

I do not want to use multiple Canvas as I need to save this canvas as an image as a whole.

```
            var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
                imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

                function handleImage(e){
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function(event){

                        var img = new Image();
                        img.onload = function(){
                            canvas.width = 760;
                            canvas.height = 300;
                        }
                        img.src = event.target.result;
                        img.onload = function(){
                            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                        };
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Canvas does not have layers.

But you can still get 1 final image with both your background and your user's scaled/rotated foreground.

Since you want to let the user rotate/scale their image but you don't want to affect the background, you will need 2 canvases -- a background canvas and a user canvas.

```
// HTML

<div id="container">
  <canvas id="background" class="subcanvs" width=760 height=300></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas" class="subcanvs" width=760 height=300></canvas>
</div>

// CSS

#container{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:760px;
  height:300px;
}
.subcanvs{
  position:absolute;
}


// JavaScript 

// a background canvas
var background=document.getElementById("background");
var bkCtx=background.getContext("2d");

// a foreground canvas the user can rotate/scale
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Then when the user is done rotating/scaling, drawImage the users canvas to the background canvas.

```
// combine the users finished canvas with the background canvas
bkCtx.drawImage(canvas,0,0);

// and save the background canvas (now it's combined) as an image
var imageURL=background.toDataURL();
```